# Search results missing results from NAS for one domain in One-Way Trust

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

I have a 2010 Farm setup in a One-Way Trust Environment.  All farm service accounts are on domain B and all users are a mix from Domain A and B. I have a NAS that is configured to allow R/W access for Everyone and a NAS content source that is indexing the share.

Domain B users can get while domain A users get no results from the NAS.  Is there anyway to disable trimming for an individual content source, or is there some other way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Search respects NTFS permissions for file shares.  So, you would need to ensure the users from the other domain have explicit security access on the file shares.  (i.e. read access for domainA\domain users and read access for domainB\domain users).